# Average Percentage Change for Positive & Negative % changes

Tags: percentages

How do you calculate the average percentage change for the following:

1) +5.2%

2) -1.25%

3) -1.74%

4) +4.21%

Using all four numbers together.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it in terms of "what are we multiplying by?".

In case 1), you multiply by $1.052$

In case 2) you multiply by $.9875$

So multiply all four of those factors together.

Then figure out what other number could you multiply by itself 4 times to get the same result.  I'll show a formula if that doesn't make sense or you can't work through that.